# error message:An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, textbox

Hello please im working on a restaurant management system and Im tyring to compute the cost of items  when the total button is clicked. im not very familiar with c# but i keep getting an the error message:An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

the code

```
    private void btntotal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        double[] itemtotal = new double[12];
        itemtotal[0] = Convert.ToDouble(txtspringroll.Text) * Price_springroll;
        itemtotal[1] = Convert.ToDouble(txtsamosa.Text) * Price_samosa;
        itemtotal[2] = Convert.ToDouble(txtsalmon.Text) * Price_salmon;
        itemtotal[3] = Convert.ToDouble(txttarator.Text) * Price_tarator;
        itemtotal[4] = Convert.ToDouble(txtshkembe.Text) * Price_shkembe;
        itemtotal[5] = Convert.ToDouble(txtguveche.Text) * Price_guveche;
        itemtotal[6] = Convert.ToDouble(txtbanista.Text) * Price_banista;
        itemtotal[7] = Convert.ToDouble(txtgarash.Text) * Price_garash;
        itemtotal[8] = Convert.ToDouble(txtbaklava.Text) * Price_baklava;
        itemtotal[9] = Convert.ToDouble(txtwater.Text) * Price_water;
        itemtotal[10] = Convert.ToDouble(txtcoke.Text) * Price_coke;
        itemtotal[11] = Convert.ToDouble(txtapple.Text) *Price_apple;


        totalcost = itemtotal[0] + itemtotal[1] + itemtotal[2] + itemtotal[3] + itemtotal[4] + itemtotal[5] + itemtotal[6] + itemtotal[7] + itemtotal[8] + itemtotal[9] + itemtotal[10] + itemtotal[11];
        txtTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(totalcost);


    }
```

Comment: Seems like one of textboxes does not have text which is convertable to double value. I recommend you to use `NumericUpDown` for entering numeric values

Comment: have you check all text box have valid double values?

Comment: Your problem has been explained above, but you should know that you can use _itemtotal[].Sum()_ method and if you handle money values the correct datatype to use is _decimal_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting an exception when Convert.ToDouble receives a string that is not a valid number. (Even a blank string is invalid to this method).
To convert a text input to a numeric value, without getting exceptions when the input is not a valid number, you should use the TryParse method appropriate for your datatype.

But when dealing with money values you should use the decimal datatype to avoid rounding errors caused by the floating point types.

```
decimal[] itemtotal = new decimal[12];

// If the conversion succeed the itemtotal[0] contains the converted value
// otherwise it contains the default value for a decimal (0)
decimal.TryParse(txtspringroll.Text, out itemtotal[0]);
itemtotal[0] *= Price_springroll;

// and so on for the other elements of the array

txtTotal.Text = itemtotal.Sum().ToString();
```